# Execute single Javascript file with headless chrome from the command line

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, command-line-interface, chromium

We use PhantomJS as simple test runner like this:

```
phantomjs path/to/test.js
```

Is there a similar way with headless chrome?

Answer (score 4):

[Selenium WebDriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver) is a NPM package that can help you to run a headless browser.

Try the below example:

```js
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

const width = 640;
const height = 480;

let driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(
        new chrome.Options().headless().windowSize({width, height}))
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr')
    .then(_ =>
        driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN))
    .then(_ => driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000))
    .then(
        _ => driver.quit(),
        e => driver.quit().then(() => { throw e; }));
```

According to the [API](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html), the driver methods return Promises and, as a result, can be called using the `async`/`await` syntax:

```js
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

async function test() {
    const width = 640;
    const height = 480;

    let driver = new Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(
            new chrome.Options().headless().windowSize({width, height}))
        .build();

    await driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr')
    await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN))
    await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000))
    await driver.quit()
}

test();
```

Comment: What are the dependencies for this? `require('..')` makes it hard to know what I should install first.

Comment: According to the [README in the selenium-webdriver repo](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/trunk/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver#using-the-builder-api), `Builder`, `By`, `Key` and `until` come from [selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver). Chrome and Firefox are required from "selenium-webdriver/chrome" and "selenium-webdriver/firefox"

Answer (score 1):

You can run you tests with Karma and headless Chrome. Here's a [guide](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/headless-karma-mocha-chai) for doing that.

Puppeteer's also pretty well-equipped to do this. Here's a [guide](https://itnext.io/getting-started-using-puppeteer-headless-chrome-for-end-to-end-testing-8487718e4d97) for that too.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer), an API for headless Chrome/Chromium.

Once you have your script (the [docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md) are good), you can run it with `node script.js`.

Answer (score 0):

[as explained on developers.google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#node) you have option of using `Node` or `Selenium`, in either case you will have to re-write part of your test cases to use the new api instead of the [`phantomjs` api](http://phantomjs.org/api/).

**The following options are based on `Node`**:

1. [`Puppeteer`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

I suggest you to head over to their [github page](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) for installation and usage instructions.

Your test case should be written using the [`Puppetteer` api](http://phantomjs.org/) and [run](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#usage) with:

```
node path/to/test.js
```

There is a list of [puppeteer resources](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/awesome-puppeteer), you can use `puppeteer` with [`jest`](https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer), [`mocha`](https://github.com/direct-adv-interfaces/mocha-headless-chrome), [`angular`](https://github.com/Quramy/angular-puppeteer-demo), [`e2e`](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/e2e)..

2. [`chrome-remote-interface`
   library](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#cri)

> [chrome-remote-interface](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#cri) is a lower-level library than Puppeteer's API. I recommend it if you want to be close to the metal and use the DevTools protocol directly.

You need to [start `chrome` in headless mode](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#cli) or use [`lighthouse`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) or `nodejs`:

```
node --inspect=9222 path/to/test.js
```

write your `javascript` test case using the [chrome `DevTools protocol`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) and follow the instructions on [their github page](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface#sample-api-usage) to install and run your tests.

**The other option is using `Selenium` configured [to run headless Chrome](https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/)**. The [following options](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#drivers) use `Selenium`:

1. [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)
2. [Webdriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)